# Connectivity issues with SSL Socket Server

Tags: sockets, sslstream

Socket Server with SSLStream some times refuses new connections from clients.

I used the telent hostname port, and it says `Connecting To host...`

> Could not open connection to the host, on port 6002: Connect failed

I used `netstat -a` , and I see TCP status as

> TCP 0.0.0.0:6002           host:0            LISTENING

I also see the service as listening in `tcpview` too.

The error I see on client side is `connection refused with error code 10061`.

The same socket server was accepting new connections and just runs fine without any issues.But after some time the above issue happens.its random.

When I restart the sockets it just works fine and accepts conenctions, which I don;t want to do it frequently.becasue this disconnects clients, who are already connected.

Could somebody help me to trouble shoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running netstat? On the server?

1. Try connecting to the socket from localhost (from the server itself) using the destination IP address 127.0.0.1
2. Do the same test with the network IP of the server.

My guess is that the firewall is preventing external access or a router in between is preventing the connection.

Comment: I followed msdn example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx.    I tried doing telnet 127.0.0.1 port , still same issue.I think this happens when client disconnects its connecions.This behaviour is not consistant

Answer (score 0):

It works for a while and then stops. Few options I can think of:

1. Some firewall on the way does some kind of throttling
2. You open and close too many connections too quickly. In this case you exhaust the ephemeral ports on the client (usually) and/or on the server. If you do netstat -a you will see a lot of sockets in TIME_WAIT state, try this both on client and server. Solution here is to reuse connections (best). Or increase the number of ephemeral ports (registry setting). But this will take you only so far.
3. You have a bug in your server and it stops accepting new connections after a while.

Comment: I followed msdn example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx.I tried doing telnet 127.0.0.1 port , still same issue.I did netstat-a , don;t see any connections with  TIME_WAIT.I think this happens when client disconnects its connecions.This behaviour is not consistant .